# AngularJS - View gets undefined data from StateProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to send an object to my `view` from the `stateProvider` in my `AngularJS` application. The `state` does resolve the object and sends it, however in the view the object is suddenly `undefined`. How can this be?

**StateProvider**

```
 ...
 .state('view', {
        url: '/view/:view',
        templateUrl: urlBase + 'views/view.html',
        controller: 'viewController',
        resolve: {
            view: function ($stateParams, sharedProperties) {
                sharedProperties.getConfig(sharedProperties)
                    .then(function(response){
                        var config = response.data;

                        console.log('config :', config);

                        for (var i = 0; i < config.views.length; i++) {
                            if (config.views[i].route === $stateParams.view) {
                                console.log('jackpot : ', config.views[i]);
                                return config.views[i];
                            }
                        }

                        return undefined;
                    })
                    .catch(function(error){
                        console.log('Error : ', error);
                        return undefined;
                    });
            }
        }
    })
...
```

**view**

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('viewController', ['$scope', '$state', '$interval', '$window', 'view', 'socketService', 'userService', 
  function ($scope, $state, $interval, $window, view, socketService, userService) {
    console.log('view : ', view);

    var user = userService.get();

    //  If there is no view, return to login page
    if (view === undefined) {
        $state.go('welcome');
    }

    /*
     *  Sets the models to be used in the view
     */
    $scope.values = view.values;
...
```

**shareProperties service**

```
app.factory('sharedProperties', function ($http) {
    var service = {};

    service.getConfig = function () {
        return $http.get('config.json');
    };

    return service;
});
```

**Console log**

```
config : Object {socketAddress: "ws://localhost:8081/Common",   IISProjectName: "simplanner", views: Array[1]} core.js:67
jackpot :  Object {route: "Arbejds Tider", viewFunctions: Object, storedProcedure: Object, values: Array[5]} view.controller.js:3
view : undefined

angular.min.js:107 TypeError: Cannot read property 'values' of undefined
    at new <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/simplanner/scripts/controllers/view.controller.js:15:29)
    at e (http://localhost:8080/simplanner/lib/Angular-1.4.7/angular.min.js:39:193)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:8080/simplanner/lib/Angular-1.4.7/angular.min.js:39:310)
    at http://localhost:8080/simplanner/lib/Angular-1.4.7/angular.min.js:80:313
    at http://localhost:8080/simplanner/lib/Angular-1.4.7/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:28006
    at aa (http://localhost:8080/simplanner/lib/Angular-1.4.7/angular.min.js:73:90)
    at K (http://localhost:8080/simplanner/lib/Angular-1.4.7/angular.min.js:62:39)
    at g (http://localhost:8080/simplanner/lib/Angular-1.4.7/angular.min.js:54:410)
    at http://localhost:8080/simplanner/lib/Angular-1.4.7/angular.min.js:53:480
    at k (http://localhost:8080/simplanner/lib/Angular-1.4.7/angular-ui-router.min.js:7:27219) <div ui-view="" class="ng-scope">
(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:107
(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:80
aa @ angular.min.js:73
K @ angular.min.js:62
g @ angular.min.js:54
(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:53
k @ angular-ui-router.min.js:7
(anonymous function) @ angular-ui-router.min.js:7
n.$broadcast @ angular.min.js:136
y.transition.M.then.y.transition.y.transition @ angular-ui-router.min.js:7
(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:119
n.$eval @ angular.min.js:133
n.$digest @ angular.min.js:130
n.$apply @ angular.min.js:133
h @ angular.min.js:87
K @ angular.min.js:91
z.onload @ angular.min.js:93
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *factory* **`sharedProperties`** has a method/function `getConfig()` - which result we want. So we have to `return` it:

```
...
resolve: {
    view: function ($stateParams, sharedProperties) {
        // instead of just a call
        // sharedProperties.getConfig(sharedProperties)

        // we need to return that result
        return sharedProperties.getConfig(sharedProperties)

            .then(function(response){
            ...
```

Comment: That's it. I'll tig this as the solution in 9 minutes ^^

Comment: Great to see that Michael ;) Enjoy mighty UI-Router ;)